# Why are my unchecked f.check_boxes giving default value of "1" in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a checkbox below. It's rendering properly (unchecked) but submitting with a value of "1". I want the unchecked boxes to have default values of 0.

```
<%= builder.check_box :content, :class=>"yesno", :data => {:'on-text' =>"YES", :'off-text' =>"NO", :question => question.id} %>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Does this has anything to do with `jQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
<%= builder.check_box :content, {:class=>"yesno", :data => {:'on-text' =>"YES", :'off-text' =>"NO", :question => question.id}}, 0, 1 %>
```

As per the [check_box](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) documentation:

> The `checked_value` defaults to **1** while the default `unchecked_value` is set to **0** which is convenient for *boolean* values.